# How to chain {% includes %} in django templating

Tags: python, html, django

I have a `base.html` file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>

{% block header %}{% endblock %}

</head>
<body>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and I have a file, `auth.html` that extends this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

[MY CONTENT]

{% endblock %}
```

which works fine, but I also want to have a separate `header.html` file that plugs into the `header` block above.

**What's the correct way to structure `auth.html` and `header.html` in order to include both and to have both extend `base.html`?**

I tried adding a `{% include header.html %}` line to `auth.html`, and structuring `header.html` as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block header %}

[HEADER CONTENT HERE]

{% endblock %}
```

but that didn't work. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need `{{ block.super }}`:

> If you need to get the content of the block from the parent template,
>   the {{ block.super }} variable will do the trick. This is useful if
>   you want to add to the contents of a parent block instead of
>   completely overriding it.

Its burried in the [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) documentation.

---

Suppose you want to add extra stuff to the `header` block in `auth.html`. `header` is defined in `index.html`:

Your `auth.html` would look like:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block header %}
{{ block.super }} 
Your extra stuff, which will come after whatever was in the header block
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: sorry, in this case my view is going to point to `auth.html` -- how would I structure the corresponding `auth.html` and `header.html` files to leverage `{{ block.super }}`?

Comment: sorry, in this case, I have two files, `auth.html` and `header.html` -- how do I get them both to extend `base.html`?